# Objective-c pass arguments to postinstall script

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm developing an app for macOS and created an installation wizard using Objective-c and pack it with `packages` to create the pkg bundle.

The wizard is collecting some configuration that needs to be set on the application after the files have been installed, I'm doing the configuration in the post-installation script of the package so I need to pass all the configurations from the Objective-c wizard to the script.

I have tried to use `launchctl setenv <key> <value>` to set the configurations and read them in the post-installation script but it does not work, I think it is executed in a different context so the varaiables are not there.

Currently, I'm writing all the configuration to a file and parse it after but I assume there is a better way.

Comment: Don't assume there's a better way. I built installers like this for years, and writing a temporary file was exactly how I passed data from installer plugins into the script.

Comment: The only issue with this method is that some configurations are passwords that I would like to avoid writing to disk.

Comment: Environment variables are also visible (though the point is taken). The better question is whether you can avoid using passwords. An authentication token is a much better solution, and limits the risk. But the other solution for sensitive information is to store it in Keychain, and then use `security` to read it back in your script. It may be hard to do this without having the user authorize it twice, however.